# Web crawling in java

Tags: java, xml, web-crawler

I have a situation where I need to crawl a set of webpages which contains just some xml data and I want to get an attribute of a particular element . How can I do this in java ?

Say , the xml strurcture is

```
<page>
       <student id=2406>
        .
        .
       </student>

       .
       . 
       . 
</page>
```

I need to crawl a lot of pages so please suggest a fast crawler

edit:
      I have seen some pages relating to this but I didn't find a fair answer. Also any code would be appreciated

Comment: You are looking for an XML parser which doesn't force well-formed input

Comment: you might want to take a look at: [DOM in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html)

Comment: @ Daniel : The major problem is crawling . If I get the xml data from crawler , I can use SAX parser to get attribute .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jsoup** would be a good crawler. Here's what you can do with it:

```
String xml = "this would be your xml";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
for (Element e : doc.select("tag")) {
    System.out.println(e); //this will print the node with "tag"
}
```

To crawl a web page, use the following code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();
```

Comment: @ Joel : Thanks for your answer . but I guess there is no "select" method in Document class

Comment: There is, document class here refers to the one in the Jsoup library. Anyways if for crawling purpose Jsoup does a perfect job for you!